# How can I calculate the interquartile range of a group of overlaying pixels using the raster calculator function in R?

Tags: r, raster-calculator

I am able to find the mean, min, and max, but I can't get the interquartile range when I replace mean with "iqr" for instance.

This works:

```
list <- list.files(path="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Rasterize\\", full.names=TRUE)
STACK1 <- stack(list)
MEAN<- calc(STACK1, fun = mean)
```

This doesn't:

```
list <- list.files(path="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Rasterize\\", full.names=TRUE)
STACK1 <- stack(list)
IQR <- calc(STACK1, fun = iqr)
```

Comment: what does it do? Where does `iqr` come from? Works for me when I make a test raster and use `iqr` from the `EnvStats` package...

Comment: That was my issue!  I didn't install the EnvStats package.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help. You should always include the error messages in your question.